# C# Linq with Groupby like items

Tags: c#, linq

I've been working on this for a while and have tried a couple of different ways.  I'm trying to group like items (i.e. StartWith 60 or 20) as part of the output but it doesn't work when I try StartsWith in Groupby section.

Also... instead of using 60 or 20 on the output, is there a way to rename to 60 = Vendor and 20 = Internal?

```
        var query = referenceDt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(results => results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode").ToString().StartsWith("60") ||
                              results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode").ToString().StartsWith("20")
            )
            .GroupBy(results => new
            {
                //FaultCode = results.Field<int>("FaultCode")
                FaultCode = results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode").ToString().StartsWith("60") ||
                            results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode").ToString().StartsWith("20")
            })
            .OrderBy(newFaultCodes => newFaultCodes.Key.FaultCode)
            .Select(newFaultCodes => new
            {
                FaultCode = newFaultCodes.Key.FaultCode,
                Count = newFaultCodes.Count()
            })
            ;
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you get an error? Also, why not just compare it directly to 60/20? Your logic will always result in a group `true`, since you filter them out in the where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
.GroupBy(results => new
{
    FaultCode = results.Field<Int32>("FaultCode").ToString().StartsWith("60") ? 60 : 20
})
```

And

```
.Select(newFaultCodes => new
{
    FaultCode = newFaultCodes.Key.FaultCode.ToString().StartsWith("60") 
                ? "Vendor" : "Internal",
    Count = newFaultCodes.Count()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I greatly appreciate it.  Been doing this only for a couple of weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a mapping of all prefixes somewhere and map the the corresponding value.  You can use a dictionary or join with another table.

e.g.,

```
var faultTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["20"] = "Internal",
    ["60"] = "Vendor",
};
var query =
    from r in referenceDt.AsEnumerable()
    let faultCode = r.Field<int>("FaultCode")
    let faultCodeStr = Convert.ToString(faultCode).Substring(0, 2)
    where new[] { "20", "60" }.Contains(faultCodeStr)
    group faultCode by faultTypes[faultCodeStr] into g
    select new
    {
        FaultType = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
    };
```